# How to make a new item in a list with some predefined info

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form

I want to create a list when we hire new people
Then HR needs to type in "the new info" name, date etc.

but i then want the list to have a lot of tasks that needs to be done like "setup IT equipment, book intro meeting and so on
these tasks have to be assigned to different people in our company

So everytime HR employes a new person, they go in an and type the new info and then the rest is automatically created

(we use sharepoint online)

Comment: You might take a look into workflows and create items into an task list. That might be a suitable solution for you.